# give the same login as password

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to give a password for a specific  user 
but when I use password '123' as an example 
he shows me this message
You can not create a new user from here
To create a new user, please use the control panel
how to fix that

this is my code py

```
 class access_teacher(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'res.partner'
  is_teacher = fields.Boolean(string="Is teacher")

 def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
    vals_user = {'password':'123'}
    user_obj.create(cr, uid, vals_user, context)
    result = super(access_teacher, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
      #to test if user = is_teacher
        #vals['password_crypt'] = '123'
        #self.env['res.users'].write({'password': '123'})

    return result
```

Comment: Your snippet of code is not very enlightening without any context.

Answer (score 0):

That Warning error is happening because you aren't providing a login value for the user in the vals_user dict. Just add the `login` key with a value(often an email) and you would be ok